# Replacing part of dataset A with dataset B

Tags: r, replace, sapply

I'm trying to replace a chunck of a dataset A (say, the columns 7 to 25 for some rows listed in a vector "rows") with a dataset B of the same size. The dataset B repeats one row whose values are contained in the vector "new_values." I tried the following code:

```
A[rows, 7:25] <- sapply(A[rows, 7:25], replace, values=new_values, list= 1:ncol(A[rows, 7:25]))
```

It's not working, however. What is happening is that the columns in A are all the same and each row has a different value in "new_values"

Any idea how to fix that?

Thank you!

Comment: It would be helpful to have a reproducible example. If you are unfamiliar with how to create a reproducible example, I find this resource to be helpful:njtierney.com/post/2017/01/11/magic-reprex

Comment: `A[rows, 7:25]=B`??

Comment: Yes, so actually, this works quite well: 
oes16[rows, 7:25] <- new_values[rep(1, length(rows)),]